# How to get all the matching values from '$in' operator in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, query-string

I have multiple checkboxes for different categories of blogs -

[image]

And what I want to achieve is that when I select some categories and click on filter, the specified selected blogs would be shown. I used query string parameters or URL parameters to send all the selected checkbox values to the nodejs backend -

`query` is an array containing all the selected categories

```
const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/blog/all?categories=${query}`)
```

And in the backend -

```
const cat = req.query.categories;

const all = await blogModel.find({ category: { $in: cat } });
```

I am passing the `cat`, which again consists of all the selected categories from the frontend, to `$in` to find all the matching blogs.

But the issue I am facing is that I am not getting matching blogs, say when I select the 'Science' checkbox and click on the filter I am able to get all the blogs having 'Science' as a category. But when I select say 'Science' & 'Food', I am getting an empty array as output even though I do have blogs of both categories in my MongoDB.

Backend console log of `cat` when I select 'Science' category -

[image]

And when I select 'Science' & 'Food' -

[image]

I get an empty array as output instead of all the blogs of 'Science' & 'Food' categories.

To summarize , when i select more than one categories i am getting an empty array instead of the blogs of the selected categories.And when i select only one category then i am able to get the selected blogs.It's not working for multiple categories

I am sure I am missing out on something but don't know what to google to get correct results. I also went through similar StackOverflow questions but I was not able to wrap my head around what needs to be done. I am building a simple blog website for my portfolio & thought of adding this 'filter by category' feature so that I would get to learn on how to filter values from MongoDB using mongoose. Please help me resolve this issue. Thank You.

Edit 1 - This is an example of a document from my collection
[image]

Also 'console.log(req.query.categories)' outputs this when i select 'Science' & 'Food' from the above checkbox  -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you didnt path data as `array` to mongo query
first split by `,` and then pass to query

```
const cat = req.query.categories;
cat = cat.split(",")
const all = await blogModel.find({ category: { $in: cat } });
```

Comment: Hello @mohammad Naimi , I tried adding the line of code you mentioned but now nothing is getting filtered.I am getting all the blogs even though i select some categories.

Comment: try it 
`const all = await blogModel.find({ category: { $in: ["Food"] } });`
and see if there any results ?

Comment: Yes , now only blogs of 'Food' category is showing up whenever i select any category.

Comment: I am facing this issue only when i select more than one categories , when selecting only one category i am able to filter out the blogs.

Comment: did you add array hard code ?

Comment: I finally resolved my issue , I changed the 'const cat' to 'var const' as a 'const' cannot be reassigned.Then did 'cat = cat.split(",")' to change it into an array as mentioned by you before.And was able to succesfully filter out the blogs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there seems no issue in your query, make sure you are passing right data to backend like you saved "food" as category in database and searching for "Food" it will return empty array as it is case sensitive.
`db.Posts.find({category: { $in:["Food","Gaming"]}})`
You can also try this way to fetch
`db.Posts.aggregate([{$match:{category: {$in:["cat","dog"]}}}])`

Comment: Hello @kumol , the name of all the categories are all same in both the database & the frontend i.e 'Food' and such.I tried the 'aggregate' one you mentioned and it didnt worked.I was getting all the blogs everytime.

Comment: I am facing this issue only when i select more than one categories , when selecting only one category i am able to filter out the blogs.

Comment: Would you please share one collection example of your database and  result of console.log(req.query.categories)

Comment: I added the respective pictures you asked for , please check the edit.Thank you

Comment: You are passing an array of  category in query parameter, but it is getting received as a string in nodejs. so first split this string based on comma "," it will create an object change this object to array then use this array in search filter 
"// let cat = req.query.category ? req.query.category.split(",") : []
    let categories = Object.entries(cat).map(ca=>{return ca[1]});
.find({category: {$in:categories}})//"
please keep your parameter like => category=cat,tiger

Comment: Thank you for the valuable insight.I finally solved my issue.I changed the 'const cat' to 'var const' as a 'const' cannot be reassigned.Then did 'cat = cat.split(",")' to change it into an array as mentioned by @mohammad Naimi above.And was able to succesfully filter out the blogs.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

const cat = req.query.categories;
var splitcat  = cat .split(",");

db.Posts.find({category: { $in:splitcat  }})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.